# Re-rendering jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have following jquery function:

```
        jQuery('.button').click(function(e) {               
            if(!isMobile) {
                jQuery('.button').featherlight({                        
                });                                         
            }   
        })
```

This creates an lightbox at the bottom of `<body>` like below:

Before lightbox is opened:

```
<body>
    <button> Show lightbox</button>
    <script src="https://...jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://...custom_js.js"></script>
</body>
```

After lightbox is opened:

```
<body>
    <button> Show lightbox</button>
    <script src="https://...jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://...custom_js.js"></script>
    <div class="lightbox">Lightbox content</div>
</body>
```

Problem is that none of the jQuery function inside of this lightbox works as it was created after the page was loaded.

How do I "re-render" a js file after the lightbox is created?

Thanks!

Here is an example:

```
jQuery('#tags').keyup(function(e){
    console.log(e);                    
     if(e.which == 188) {
        var tag  = ...;
        var data = '<button>tag</button>';
        tags.push(tag);
        jQuery('.tags ul').append(data);
        jQuery(this).val('');
                }               
        });
```

Here, a tag input will be "appended" or added to a div class="tags". However inside of the lightbox, this function is not executed at all.

Comment: You shouldn't have to; it's not clear what you're actually doing, when, or how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-rendering a JS file is not how javascript is supposed to work.

What I recommend you to do is to run the a function in the `afterContent` callback.

As you can see in the featherlight documentation, there is a plenty of callbacks that can help you with this.

Example:

```
 jQuery('.button').click(function(e) {               
        if(!isMobile) {
            jQuery('.button').featherlight({

                afterContent: function () {
                    // Do your code here
                    // The lightbox content will be ready
                }

            });                                         
        }   
    })
```

Comment: I see the logic behind it. What if the function that is being executed is from a large library? like google's material.min.js?

Comment: I'm sure that large libraries provide a way to `re-render` their code whenever you need. Unless it's a large library from < 2005.

Like Facebook SDK. If you need to parse a XFBML tag created after the script first run, you can `FB.XFBML.parse();` or `FB.XFBML.parse(specificDomElementToParse);`

Comment: In the case of material library. To render a element created after the dom is ready you use `componentHandler.upgradeDom();`

Comment: Thank you for the specification in terms of material library. Could you show me an example where I would use the above? For example, I have a form with the following div and input: `"<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield"><input class="mdl-textfield__input"></input></div>"`. Also, I will do some research on what you provided :) thanks.

Comment: Sorry. But I'm not familiar with google's material workflow. I never used it. I've just searched for how to render a element to use as an example here.

Comment: i see =) Thank you for the help thought! I am doing some research on it and will for sure share the result! =)

Answer (score 0):

The proble here is that the light ox is dynamically added.

If you need any triggers to work inside or on that lightbox element you will need to use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.lightbox .button', function(){
    ...
});
```

Note that you do not want this code inside that lightbox, but inside your regular js file. Simply because we do not like inline js, and second you can trigger every dynamic content on the fly with above code.

Comment: What if the function that is being executed is from a large library? like google's material.min.js?